# Is the following function continuous? Has partial derivatives?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(t)$ be a differentiable function for every $t$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Define:
> $$
> g(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{f(x)^2 + f(y)^2}{x^2+y^2}, &\quad (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
> 1 &\quad (x,y)=(0,0).
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Is $g$ continuous at $(0,0)$? Do the partial derivatives $g_x(0,0),g_y(0,0)$ exist?

My attempt:
We know that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$. Therefore $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}=1$.
In particular, taking the paths $y=0$ or $x=0$ leads to $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x,0)= \lim_{y\to 0} g(0,y)=0$. Trying polar coordinates leads to $g(r \cos \theta , r\sin \theta) = \frac{f(r\cos \theta) ^2 + f(r\sin \theta)^2 }{r^2}$ for $r\neq 0$. If hypothetically I would have known that somehow this limit is zero for any choice of $\theta$, this would solve the problem, but we don't know that since we don't have $f(r)^2 $ in the numerator.

First question:

> How can I prove the function is continuous at $(0,0)$?

As for partial derivatives:
Using the definition, we need to calculate
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(h,0)-g(0,0) }{h } = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)^2-h^2 }{h^3 }.
$$
My intuition is that this limit doesn't exist, but choosing $f(x)=sin(x)$ or $f(x)=x$ seems to do work. So, second question is:

> What might be a possible counterexample for the existence of partial derivatives?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to manipulate the small $o(\cdot)$ notation, e.g. does writing $f(x) = x + o(x)$ make sense for you? Do you see how to use it to prove the continuity? For the counter-example, have you tried more singular functions, for example do you know a function which is differentiable once but not twice at $0$?

Comment: Unfortunately no, we cannot use the small $o$ notation, since it isn't part of this course syllabus. As for the counter example - do you mean something like $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints towards solutions.

- **Continuity.** Let us gather some intuition. From the fact that $f$ is differentiable with $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$, you know that, for $x$ very small, $f(x) \approx x$ (informal notation here, to mean that $f(x)$ is almost equal to $x$, plus some small remainder). From this, you derive that $(f(x))^2 \approx x^2$. Hence $(f(x))^2+(f(y))^2 \approx x^2 + y^2$, thus $g(x,y) \approx (x^2+y^2)/(x^2+y^2) = 1$ for small $x$ and $y$. So you get the intuition that $g$ should be continuous. Now to prove it, you can follow these informal steps by making them rigorous starting from the differentiability of $f$ and writing down what is means.
- **Partial derivatives.** The key point is that you need to start from a function $f$ which is (continuous and) differentiable, but not more regular than that. For example, $f(x) = x$ or $f(x) = \sin x$ are too regular to yield counter-examples. A usual example of a continuous function which is not differentiable is $x \mapsto |x|^{\frac 12}$. You can "translate" this example in the regularity space by using $x \mapsto |x|^{\frac 32}$ which is continuous, differentiable, but not twice differentiable. (I encourage you to draw plots).